# How do I convert an any array to a string array containing other datatypes inside in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, typescript, any

I'm doing a typescript tutorial exercise that wants me to change an any[] array into string[].

```
// declaring an array of any datatype
const  manufacturers: any[] = [{ id: 'Samsung', checked: false },
        { id: 'Motorola', checked: false },
        { id: 'Apple', checked: false },
        { id: 'Sony', checked: false }
    ];

console.log('Available Products are: ');

 // logic to populate the above declared array's id value
for (const item of manufacturers) {

     console.log(item.id);
    if(item.id === "Apple")
    {
        console.log("check value is " + item.checked)
    }
    }
```

The above one works, but if I change any[] into string[], it doesn't work. If I do

`"const  manufacturers: [string,boolean][]="`
then it recognizes the boolean and not the string. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't see id as a string variable and make it match. How do I accomplish this without using 'any[]'

Comment: You don't have to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) variables, you know.  You can just write `const manufacturers = [{ id: 'Samsu...` and the compiler will *infer* the type as `{ id: string; checked: boolean; }[]` (you can see by hovering over `manufacturers` in an IntelliSense-enabled IDE like VSCode).  If you must annotate the variable, you can first let the compiler infer it, and then copy that inferred type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nlx6RN).

Comment: Note that `[string, boolean][]` would look like `[["Samsung", false], ["Motorola", false]]` and not `[{id: "Samsung", checked: false}, {id: "Motorola, checked: false}]`.  If this makes sense to you I could write up an answer; if not, let me know what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz That's interesting. It would be nice if the tutorial told me what it was looking for. It just said "Modify the datatype of the manufacturer's array as a string and re-execute the code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `manufacturers` is `{ id: string, checked: boolean }[]`.

**Explanation:**

The `manufacturers` object is an array, containing objects. Each object has an `id` and a `checked` property which are of types string and boolean respectively.

So as you said, changing from `any[]` to `string[]` won't work, because the `manufacturers` type is not `string[]`, but `{ id: string, checked: boolean }[]`.

```js
const manufacturers: { id: string, checked: boolean }[] = [{ id: 'Samsung', checked: false },
{ id: 'Motorola', checked: false },
{ id: 'Apple', checked: false },
{ id: 'Sony', checked: false }
];

console.log('Available Products are: ');

for (const item of manufacturers) {

  console.log(item.id);
  if (item.id === "Apple") {
    console.log("check value is " + item.checked)
  }
}
```

As @Calz pointed out, you don't need to explicitly enter the type of the variable, as initialization is taking place at the time of declaration.

Here's a small example explaining this:

```js
let a;
a = 5
console.log(typeof a) // number
a = "string"
console.log(typeof a) // string

let b = 5
b = "some string"; // error as TypeScript blames that type string is not assignable to type number
```